# sqlite3 - table_info looks messy

Tags: sqlite, command-line

I created a new database by using the command line binary on Suse.
After activating headers by using `.headers ON` it still looks messy when getting table information with `PRAGMA table_info(TABLE1);`:

```
cid|name|type|notnull|dflt_value|pk
0|COLUMN1|REAL|1||0
```

How can I achieve a cleaner look like this:

```
sqlite> pragma table_info(member);
cid      name          type     notnull  dflt_value  pk     
-------  ------------  -------  -------  ----------  -------
0        account_id    text     1                    0      
1        account_name  text     1                    0
```

Comment: You could try using one of the available GUI tools - the whole point of SQLite is the "Lite" part - using a  GUI tool could allow you to have a pleasant UX while retaining SQLite's lean and mean nature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `sqlite3` command-line shell, this [output format](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#changing_output_formats) can be selected with `.mode column`.